# ffmpeg convert AVFrame from yuv420p to argb

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm tring to decode h.264 stream buffer on android using ffmpeg 3.3.
I got an  **AVFrame** structure  from the stream successfully, it's format is **AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P**. In order to display the image on **android**, I need to convert it to **AV_PIX_FMT_ARGB** or **AV_PIX_FMT_RGB565**. I tried many times, finally I find that I can convert the frame to **AV_PIX_FMT_NV21** but cannot convert it to argb or rgb565 using almost same code except some arguments.Here is my code looks like:

```
//here i got srcFrame from h264 stream, it's format and size was set by decoder correctly

AVFrame *dstFrame = av_frame_alloc();
dstFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_ARGB;
dstFrame->width = srcFrame->width;
dstFrame->height = srcFrame->height;

struct SwsContext *swsContext = sws_getContext(srcFrame->width, srcFrame->height, srcFormat,
                                               dstFrame->width, dstFrame->height,
                                               (enum AVPixelFormat) dstFrame->format,
                                               SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);

int dstBufferSize = av_image_get_buffer_size((enum AVPixelFormat) dstFrame->format, ctx->width,
                                             ctx->height, 1);
uint8_t *dstBuffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(
        sizeof(uint8_t) * dstBufferSize);

av_image_fill_arrays(dstFrame->data, dstFrame->linesize, dstBuffer,
                     (enum AVPixelFormat) dstFrame->format, dstFrame->width,
                     dstFrame->height,
                     1);

sws_scale(swsContext, (const uint8_t *const *) srcFrame->data,
          srcFrame->linesize, 0, srcFrame->height,
          dstFrame->data, dstFrame->linesize);
```

Comment: How are you displaying the frames? openGL ES or another method?

Comment: There are some ways I hadn't try, see the SurfaceHolder's comment,you will find lockCanvas method and surfaceCreate callback.

Comment: In all my players I've used openGL ES and a YUV420 shader. I still use the sws_scale to copy into my queued buffers still as YUV420 as it trims off the edges of the frames and less overhead than converting the RGB.

Comment: @WLGfx  It's my mistake, I display the rgb buffer to Surface by NDK successfully.